# How do you write a function 'such that' in purely mathematical terms?

Tags: functions, notation

For example, say I've already defined a function $g$. Then I'd like to write, in purely mathematical terms, "the function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(a)$ equals $g(x)$." Sometimes, I see the full stop being used to indicate "such that", although the problem is that if there's then a full stop at the end of the statement it can look a bit ambiguous.

$$f:A\to B.f(a)=g(x).$$

Is there a better, less ambiguous way, than this?

Comment: Yes, you write "such that". It's short and clear. No reason to do something else.

Comment: There's no reason to use notation if words would be clearer. It's not  "more mathematical" to use notation.

Comment: In set-builder notation, we sometimes use a colon or a vertical line to represent such that.  Also, s.t. is sometimes used to abbreviate such that.

Comment: I agree that the best option is to say "such that", but some of my professors used a colon, a slash \ or two commas ,, to buy time. Anyway, you have to explain the notation to the reader at least once, since they are not universally used.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `align` environment is fairly common to define functions while stating the domain and codomain, as in

\begin{align*} 
f \colon A &\to B \\ 
a &\mapsto \text{whatever $a$ gets mapped to,}
\end{align*}

but it looks kind of odd here (but then again, your condition is just plain odd!):

\begin{align*} 
f \colon A &\to B \\ 
a &\mapsto g(x).
\end{align*}

I've also seen $\in$ backwards, as in $\ni$, to be a symbol for "such that" but I don't like it, personally.